# Getting OutofBoundSDateTime on pandas to_datetime origin Parameter when origin='julian'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

origin2 = pd.to_datetime([1,2,3],unit='D',origin='julian')
origin2

on the above command getting the following issue :

OutOfBoundsDatetime                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 origin2 = pd.to_datetime([1,2,3],unit='D',origin='julian')
      2 origin2

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    206                 else:
    207                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 208             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    209 
    210         return wrapper

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    750 
    751     if origin != "unix":
--> 752         arg = _adjust_to_origin(arg, origin, unit)
    753 
    754     tz = "utc" if utc else None

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _adjust_to_origin(arg, origin, unit)
    515             raise tslibs.OutOfBoundsDatetime(

.......
OutOfBoundsDatetime: [1, 2, 3] is Out of Bounds for origin='julian'

Answer (score 0):

The range for Julian calendar is from **2333836 to 2547339** (from Timestamp('1677-09-21 12:00:00') to Timestamp('2262-04-11 12:00:00')), so **[1, 2, 3]** are OutOfBoundsDatetime, like error said.